# Docker --name causes ambiguous error

Tags: docker

This is a bit of a newb question, but I want to run this docker command:

```
docker run \
--name $NAME_ASTERISK \
--net=host \
-v $(pwd)/test/example/:/etc/asterisk/ \
-d -t dougbtv/asterisk
```

It outputs this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (--net=host), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed.
```

This to me suggests docker believes I am passing the --net line into the --name option and naturally choking on it. This is copy pasted from the project in question (https://github.com/dougbtv/docker-asterisk) so I assume the command is valid (I've rarely worked with multiline commands and I'm not entirely certain on the syntax).

Are there any obvious issues with this command?

Comment: This is probably due to the fact `$NAME_ASTERISK` is empty. Check its value by using `echo "$NAME_ASTERISK"` before your docker command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ docker run \
  --name $NAME_ASTERISK \
  --net=host \
  -v $(pwd)/test/example/:/etc/asterisk/ \
  -d -t dougbtv/asterisk

docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (--net=host), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed.
```

This indicates the first argument docker sees after `--name` is `--net=host`. If `$NAME_ASTERISK` is undefined or empty, that will be the case. Define the variable first with something like:

```
NAME_ASTERISK=asterisk
```

and try running your command again.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue.